# Sum column based on header criteria in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum all the quantity sold in all orders here so that sheet will search for Q in column header if its there the sum the below no.

below is a link for my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1viATMfTjVHSLrC1HTYKArmJBnrDfeNVj7oSIgdVzLH4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C5:BJ)*(C4:BJ4="Q"))
```

[image]